# Adobe AIR Interface Name Format

Tags: apache-flex, networking, air, adobe, ethernet

Using this code:

```
results = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
for (var i:int =0; i<results.length; i++) {
     ethName = ethName + results[i].name
}
```

I get this result:

`{E9742B69-3B80-471A-AF41-B38753474834}`

I thought I'd get either the hardware information for the interface or the name.  What is this?  Anyone have a similar result?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that was some unique ID assigned to the hardware.  Since you're concatenating with no distinguishing separator; it's tough to tell how many items are returned in results; and where a single item ends and the next one begins.

Comment: Hello, That is one single item.  I did  not post the other which is just the Loopback Interface.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Mac address; it looks like a windows reg key.  But, I'm not sure why you'd get that back.  Hopefully someone more knowledgeable on this stuff can help.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It is supposed to be "en0" or the adapter specific information, not the key.  I wondered why this was the case.